# PHP posting on page wall

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website where users can post jobs for free. How can I link these posts to a facebook page about this website? I don't want the users to login to fb.
At this moment I post them to twitter and then using selective tweets to post them on my page. But selective tweets is not able to post logo's specific for that job.

I created a fb app. Did not select anything just gave it a name and got an appID and appSecret. I dont now what to select in "Select how your app integrates with Facebook". Becouse it is not a mobile app and it is not a website with fb login.

Kind regards.

Comment: It must be a website with fb login. When you have a visitor and you want to post on the wall, how do you even know that he facebook account, if he is not logged in?

Comment: @IvanKuckir it's not about the user's facebook account. If I've read it correctly, the jobs get posted to a site regardless, he just wants to somehow collect them to a single facebook page for their site/company, so they all become posts under his company name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use share on facebook facility of facebook ,from http://developer.facebook.com.
you can easily add this to your website. 
have fun!

Comment: The share to facebook facility requires one to press on a share to fb button. I don't want this. I just want all jobs be posted to our fb page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily via MYSQL and PHP, depending on how your current site is setup. What i would do is store the jobs into a separate table while saving, like this
(table) Facebook
pageid //numerical value
header  //job title
message //job description

So that you can use it for the next part.

Create an application via Facebook and give it authentication to users and your Facebook page.
by adding this application to your page you can then call something like :

$facebook->set_user($user, $session_key);

$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($item['header'], $item['message'], $item['pageid']);

Using your keys from facebook.

Then you can run a Cron that updates every x minutes, and after it has posted it, in an array, you can clear the table for the next row of jobs.

Let me know where you are on this and ill try to help as much as possible.